# WiX Permissions - setting a permission on a pre-existing directory

Tags: permissions, wix

I'm using the msbuild heat wrapper to generate the component list for my website installer, and trying to figure out how to define permissions on a folder deep in that tree.

In my generated wxs file I've got

```
<Directory Id="dirC092054A3A348CC48B696FD466A89A2F" Name="ExportFiles">
<Component Id="cmp699347B0054EDD7DD7B0935D39A66FAE" Guid="{5037..}">
  <File Id="..." KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Reports\ExportFiles\donotdelete.txt" />
</Component>
</Directory>
```

And I realise I could use a CreateFolder and Permission element here, but this file is regenerated on the prebuild so I'd loose my changes each time. Is there a was of setting the permission on the ExportFiles folder from within my main Product.wxs file?

Comment: A solution is using XCACLS as a custom action: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754 . This way you can set permissions on a path instead of using an ID.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a custom action and then set the permission on the folder. Use this code

```
string directory = session["PATH"] + "Temp";
if (Directory.Exists(directory))
{
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl,
            InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None,
            AccessControlType.Allow));
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}
```

This code will make the folder shared to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Although Sunil's answer does work, I found another way which I thought I'd share.

I'm using the technique outlined [here](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/07/30/how-to-consume-msdeploy-staged-web-site-output-in-a.aspx) to get heat.exe to grab the staged output of my web app, but with a couple of modifications:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<MSBuild Projects="%(ProjectReference.FullPath)" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=AnyCPU" Condition="'%(ProjectReference.WebProject)'=='True'" />
<Copy SourceFiles="%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\TransformWebConfig\transformed\web.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" DestinationFolder="%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\" />
<PropertyGroup>
  <LinkerBaseInputPaths>%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\</LinkerBaseInputPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
<HeatDirectory OutputFile="%(ProjectReference.Filename)-temp.xml" Directory="%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\" DirectoryRefId="INSTALLLOCATION" ComponentGroupName="%(ProjectReference.Filename)_Project" SuppressCom="true" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRegistry="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" AutoGenerateGuids="false" GenerateGuidsNow="true" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" Condition="'%(ProjectReference.WebProject)'=='True'" />
<XslTransformation XmlInputPaths="%(ProjectReference.Filename)-temp.xml" XslInputPath="XslTransform.xslt" OutputPaths="%(ProjectReference.Filename).wxs" />
```

- Firstly the copy task grabs the properly transformed web.config which didn't seem to happen on its own (I was getting tokens in the staged config file).
- The heat task outputs to a temporary XML file, which I transform via XSLT into the WXS file to be picked up by WiX

Heres the XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:copy>
```

```
<xsl:template match="w:Directory[@Name='ExportFiles']/w:Component">
<w:Component>
  <xsl:attribute name="Id">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="Guid">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Guid"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <w:CreateFolder>
    <w:Permission User="Administrators" GenericAll="yes" />
    <w:Permission User="Network Service" GenericAll="yes" />
  </w:CreateFolder>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</w:Component>
```

It simply recreates the file with the exception of the ExportFiles folder which has the permission bits added:
Before:

```
<Directory Id="dirC092054A3A348CC48B696FD466A89A2F" Name="ExportFiles">
   <Component Id="cmp699347B0054EDD7DD7B0935D39A66FAE" Guid="{87D70A4F-A757-41C2-8AC9-E2904479FD45}">
     <File Id="filEC20935A3F97F24E20E1C2041AC766CA" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Reports\ExportFiles\donotdelete.txt" />
    </Component>
   </Directory>
```

After:

```
<Directory Id="dirC092054A3A348CC48B696FD466A89A2F" Name="ExportFiles">
  <w:Component Id="cmp699347B0054EDD7DD7B0935D39A66FAE" Guid="{87D70A4F-A757-41C2-8AC9-E2904479FD45}"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <w:CreateFolder>
      <w:Permission User="Administrators" GenericAll="yes" />
      <w:Permission User="Network Service" GenericAll="yes" />
    </w:CreateFolder>
    <File Id="filEC20935A3F97F24E20E1C2041AC766CA" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Reports\ExportFiles\donotdelete.txt" />
  </w:Component>
 </Directory>
```

Its quite a nice way of doing things and I've already used the same technique for doing a few other things. Hope someone else can find it useful too.